# XML: when lacking data, leave element empty or not include element at all?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm storing XML of street addresses in a database that is read by a silverlight app. This XML is my own format, so I get to decide the standard for element names, how to handle missing data etc.

I was wondering what would be the more "correct" way to deal with empty "address 2" fields when generating the XML - should I still include an "address2" element and simply let it be `<address2 />` or should I omit it altogether? The same goes for the "state" field, since it's usually empty if it's a non-US address.

I can handle either case in the silverlight app, but I just need to decide on one standard. I wasn't sure if one approach had pitfalls or if it was completely a matter of preference.

Thanks!

P.S.  I know having "address 1", "address 2" etc. isn't necessarily the best design in the first place, but that's the way the existing data is and I can't change it.

Comment: IMO: Use empty tags, even if there's no data. Code your script to process the file even if the tags are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how the ADO `DataSet` does it.  (In fact, you could just use the ADO `DataSet`.)

The `WriteXml` method serializes a `DataSet` to XML.  Each `DataRow` is serialized as an element whose name is `Table.TableName`.  Each column in the row with a non-null value is serialized as an element whose name is the column's name and whose text content is the serialized value of the column.

This makes it possible to distinguish between a column that contains the empty string and one that contains null (which is to say, `DBNull.Value`):  a column contains the empty string if there's an empty element for it, and it contains null if there's not.

Comment: That might be a reasonable way of capturing losslessly the data that you can hold in a relational database. But remember that the relational database has probably already distorted the "real-life" data model, so starting from a relational view of the data might not be the best place to start.

Comment: Given that OP is starting from a database, I don't think this approach does *too* much violence to the real world.

Answer (score 0):

There's no correct answer: you can make your own choice. (XML schema, in its wisdom, provides yet another way to represent absent data, namely as `<address2 xsi:nil="true"/>`. I've never seen the need for it, but I mention it for completeness.)

I share your view that naming the fields "address1" and "address2" is pretty bad practice to start with. It suggests some kind of legacy from systems that don't allow repeating fields, and has no place in XML design.

In fact I think many fields are naturally multi-valued. A person may have zero or more phone numbers, and that means that if we don't have a phone number for a person, the most natural representation (in my mind) is to have zero occurrences of the `<phone>` element.

There are of course some cases where you want to distinguish a property whose value is the zero-length string from a property that is absent or unknown, though I think this is less common than the relational database theorists would have us believe. But in that case you do need different representations for the two cases. (You might also want to distinguish "absent" from "unknown" - there's a difference between knowing that someone has no middle name and not knowing whether they have a middle name - but very few systems in practice are capable of maintaining data quality to that kind of precision; and if you want to do it, I suspect you want to use a stronger signal than simply an empty or omitted element.)